# Why does deno take a different amount of time depending on the command line used to invoke it?

Tags: benchmarking, deno, likwid

I'm running a few benchmarks like this:

```bash
likwid-powermeter deno run scripts/sets.deno.js 1024
```

This will return something like this:

```
Runtime: 2.99816 s
Measure for socket 0 on CPU 0
Domain CORE:
Energy consumed: 39.3306 Joules
Power consumed: 13.1182 Watt
Domain PKG:
Energy consumed: 139.635 Joules
Power consumed: 46.5737 Watt
```

However, this command line, which should be the same:

```bash
likwid-powermeter `which deno` run scripts/sets.deno.js 1024
```

Takes 8x:

```
Runtime: 17.4637 s
Measure for socket 0 on CPU 0
Domain CORE:
Energy consumed: 312.243 Joules
Power consumed: 17.8795 Watt
Domain PKG:
Energy consumed: 910.834 Joules
Power consumed: 52.1557 Watt
```

I have checked with `time`, and it does not seem to be a problem with `deno` itself; however, I don't find the same problem with other runtimes or commands. Any idea what could be the problem, or where should I look?